# Unable to open SalesForceSDK Login screen After Logging out

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

I'm using the new **MobileSync** in my app. Below you could see my **podfile**.

> ## Uncomment the next line to define a global
>
> platform for your project platform :ios, '13.0' target 'MyApp' do
>
> ```
>    # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
>
>    source 'https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS-Specs.git'
>    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
>
>    use_frameworks!
>
>    # Pods for MyApp
>
>    pod 'MobileSync'
> ```
>
> end

**Once I log out from SalesForceSDK, Again I'll have to open the SalesForceSDK Login screen.
But Unable to open the SalesForceSDK Login screen After Logging out. Here giving my console details.**

> 2021-07-11 00:04:33.710350+0530 MyApp[69622:3035323][SalesforceSDKCore] CLASS: SFUserAccountManager Logging out user 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com'.
>
> 2021-07-11 00:04:33.725606+0530 MyApp[69622:3035323][SalesforceSDKCore] CLASS: SFOAuthKeychainCredentials
> SFOAuthKeychainCredentials:revokeAccessToken: access token revoked
>
> 2021-07-11 00:04:33.737526+0530 MyApp[69622:3035323][SalesforceSDKCore] CLASS: SFOAuthKeychainCredentials
> SFOAuthKeychainCredentials:revokeRefreshToken: refresh token revoked.
> Cleared identityUrl, instanceUrl, issuedAt fields
>
> 2021-07-11 00:04:33.739295+0530 MyApp[69622:3035323]
> [SalesforceSDKCore] CLASS: SFOAuthKeychainCredentials
> SFOAuthKeychainCredentials:setIdentityUrl: invalid or nil identityUrl:
> (null)
>
> 2021-07-11 00:04:33.746165+0530 MyApp[69622:3035323][SalesforceSDKCore] CLASS: SFOAuthKeychainCredentials SFOAuthKeychainCredentials:setIdentityUrl: invalid or nil identityUrl: (null)
>
> 2021-07-11 00:04:33.754607+0530 MyApp[69622:3035323] [SalesforceSDKCore] CLASS: SFSecurityLockout Resetting passcode.
>
> 2021-07-11 00:04:33.755609+0530 MyApp[69622:3035323][SalesforceSDKCore] CLASS: SFSDKWebViewStateManager [SFSDKWebViewStateManager setSharedProcessPool:]: changing from process pool <WKProcessPool: 0x7fb7b1c59cf0; configuration = <_WKProcessPoolConfiguration: 0x600003064840>> to (null)
>
> 2021-07-11 00:04:33.759697+0530 MyApp[69622:3035323] [SalesforceSDKCore] CLASS: SFSecurityLockout App requested passcode screen cancel.  Screen is not displayed.
>
> 2021-07-11 00:04:33.824328+0530 MyApp[69622:3035323] [SalesforceSDKCore] CLASS: SFOAuthCoordinator authenticate authenticating as 3MXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX without refresh token on 'https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-retail.XXXXXX.force.com/MyApp ...
>
> 2021-07-11 00:04:33.830049+0530 MyApp[69622:3035323] [SalesforceSDKCore] CLASS: SFSDKAuthConfigUtil getMyDomainAuthConfig:loginDomain: Advanced authentication configured. Retrieving auth configuration from https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-retail.XXXXXX.force.com/MyApp/.well-known/auth-configuration
>
> 2021-07-11 00:04:34.421281+0530 MyApp[69622:3036404] [SalesforceSDKCore] CLASS: SFSDKAuthConfigUtil Successfully retrieved org auth config data from
> https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-retail.XXXXXX.force.com/MyApp/.well-known/auth-configuration
>
> 2021-07-11 00:04:34.422353+0530 MyApp[69622:3035323] [SalesforceSDKCore] CLASS: SFOAuthCoordinator loadWebViewWithUrlString:cookie: Loadi https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-retail.XXXXXX.force.com/MyApp/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=3MXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=testsfdc:///mobilesdk/detect/oauth/done&display=touch&device_id=8C9D7D45-06DF-4081-B47E-XXXXXXXXXXXX&response_type=hybrid_token&scope=web%20api%20refresh_token
>
> 2021-07-11 00:04:34.422603+0530 MyApp[69622:3035323] [SalesforceSDKCore] CLASS: SFSDKWebViewStateManager [SFSDKWebViewStateManager sharedProcessPool]: No process pool exists.
> Creating new instance.
>
> 2021-07-11 00:04:34.430200+0530 MyApp[69622:3035323] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
>
> 2021-07-11 00:04:34.430350+0530 MyApp[69622:3035323] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
>
> 2021-07-11 00:04:34.596787+0530 MyApp[69622:3035323] [SalesforceSDKCore] CLASS: SFOAuthCoordinator webView:didStartProvisionalNavigation: host=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-retail.XXXXXX.force.com : path=/MyApp/services/oauth2/authorize
>
> 2021-07-11 00:04:35.461155+0530 MyApp[69622:3035323] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <SFSDKRootController: 0x7fb7b1c682d0>.
>
> 2021-07-11 00:04:35.462132+0530 MyApp[69622:3035323][SalesforceSDKCore] CLASS: SFOAuthCoordinator webView:didStartProvisionalNavigation: host=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-retail.XXXXXX.force.com : path=/MyApp/login
>
> 2021-07-11 00:04:48.047567+0530 MyApp[69622:3035323] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service

Any help is more valuable.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

@Sreekanth G I am answering your question based on the Salesforce for iOS connected app that i had fixed earlier.
I would check the `OAuth Policies` section on your ConnectedApp and assess your OAuth settings.

[image]

Also after a glance through your console output, i want to make sure you are not performing OAuth loop ending in user lockout:

> 2021-07-11 00:04:33.754607+0530 MyApp[69622:3035323]
> [SalesforceSDKCore] CLASS: SFSecurityLockout Resetting passcode.

Also look at below links if they help determine:

- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312323&type=1&mode=1
- [ByPass Login in Salesforce SDK](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127159/bypass-login-in-salesforce-sdk)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531307/salesforce-sdk-is-not-opening-login-screen

Let me know if the above information helps!

Comment: thanks for the help. Using old pods is working well. I can able to do login and log out many times. Below are my old pods
""""""""
   pod 'SalesforceAnalytics', :path => 'myPath'
   pod 'SalesforceSDKCore', :path => 'myPath'
   pod 'SmartSync', :path => 'myPath'
   pod 'SalesforceSwiftSDK', :path => 'myPath'
   pod 'PromiseKit', :git => 'https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit', :tag => '5.0.3'.  """"""" 
                                                                                                                                               
  Not working in If use pod 'MobileSync'

Comment: any update on above my pod? is it right? what should I do?